# Error in kmeans(dataset, k) : more cluster centers than distinct data points, unused argument (header = FALSE), R

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I am trying to apply a psf model to predict the next value in a sequence of values (see the dataframe below). I keep getting the same error:

```
data_rel_1 <- structure(list(job1category = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), job2category = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), job3category = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), job4category = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 0, 2, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -99L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    job1category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), job2category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), job3category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), job4category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

```
model1 <- psf(data_rel_1)
Error in kmeans(dataset, k) : more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

I've tried adding header = FALSE in the read_csv but this is giving me the following error:

```
unused argument (header = FALSE)
```

Does anyone have experience with this or know how I can solve this?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey, where does this `psf()`function comes from (which package?)

Comment: @elielink PSF package in R